# Boolean Not Working Properly (Partial Cuts)

Tags: modifiers, normals

I'm trying to make a click pen mechanism, where a piece in the center of the cylinder in 1 spin locks in place, and in another spin it slides into one of the slots.
 I need to cut out part of a cylinder with the 2 other objects. Thing is when I try to do it, only 1 object successfully cuts the cylinder, and the other object either does nothing or cuts only 1/4 of the cylinder... And what's weird is the 2nd object is just a duplicate of the first one. I removed all doubles from all objects and the cylinder, recalculated normals,  applied rotation and scale, tried flipping normals, still no progress...
[image]
This is working Boolean cut with first object

[image]
This is the part where it just doesn't work or works weird/half way (with the second object). It's the duplicate of the first object and some why it doesn't work and I don't understand why...

Edit: Forgot to mention, I also tried joining/merging both objects together and removing dupes, still doesn't solve the problem sadly:
[image]

I would be very happy for help! Thank you in advance!

Blend File: [image]

I also checked other threads and non of them had an answer for my specific problem.

Anyways, I got to a solution but this question got closed so I couldn't answer it. Here's how I did it:
I couldn't really find a specific "right" way to fix the problem. But I used lemon's suggestions. What I did is I set both booleans to "Carve" instead of "B-Mesh" which did cut most of what I needed, just left some faces and added some edges in the middle of faces and and random vertices. After I applied the booleans I just manually deleted all the edges and random vertices and the left-over faces and remade the faces that needed to be remade. I hope this answer helps anyone in the future! Thank you [lemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kA09.png)!

Comment: As I said, I checked all objects and removed all duplicates. ATM it isn't showing any duplicates...

Comment: The first boolean makes cuts so that resulting faces are too close to the second boolean. So there is a face conflict and blender can't determinate who is inside or outside. This is not totally a duplicate of the mentioned question.

Comment: Forgot to mention but I also tried merging both objects and removing duplicates and I either get the same result or it doesn't even cut at all. The cylinder just stays as is...

Comment: To make it work, you'll have to enlarge a bit each part of the second boolean "cutter". Though I don't know if doing that still meets your need.

Comment: Merging the objects don't work either because that probably makes an inner face which causes the same issue.

Comment: Enlarging a bit of each part beats my objective :\
But isn't "Removing Duplicates" supposed to remove also the duplicate faces? I mean there can't be 2 faces between 4 vertices... From what I know of course...

Comment: No it won't remove what's needed in this case (faces are not duplicate but just one along the other). You'll need to think a bit differently how to make the object that is to use as boolean cutter here. And anyway you'll still have a face conflict on one side.

Comment: You have any suggestion on any way I could do it so it works? I'm pretty new to blender and I can't really think of a way...

Comment: The problem is I do not know where you want to go and what are the constraints to respect. Could you give them editing your question?

Comment: My bad, thought I wrote it... I edited it now. But in general I'm trying to make something similar to a click pen mechanism when one part turns and in one click, it turns 45 degrees, and locks in one of the teeth, and in another click it turns another 45 degrees and slides in the nest slots.

Comment: I don't feel it as answer as it is very specific (except the conflicting faces aspect). But here you are: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6298/  On left cheated to avoid the conflict problem. Center two cutters merged correctly. Right yours. FYI generally boolean with 'carve' is better.